# Last element of list with datetime object

Tags: python

I have 2 "ranges" of datetime objects, defined by a start and stop date.
I want to create a new "range" (start and stop date) for matching days in the first 2 ranges.

Here's what I tried, but I'm having issues with the list: it doens't seem to properly get the last element?

```
import datetime

#First date range is next week from monday to sunday:
next_week_day = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
monday = next_week_day - datetime.timedelta(days=next_week_day.weekday())
sunday = monday + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

daterange = [monday + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (sunday-monday).days)]
  
#Second daterange can be anything:
start = datetime.date(2020, 8, 2)
end = datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)
daterange_2 = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
  
#then I create a list to add matching days to create the new range
date_list = []
for date in daterange:
  for date_2 in daterange_2:
    if date_2 == date:
      date_list.append(date)

#and retrieve first and last day in list
first_date = date_list[0]
second_date = date_list[-1]

print(first_date, second_date)
print(type(first_date), type(second_date))
```

prints `'2020, 9, 24'` for second_date instead of `'2020, 9, 25'`.
What am I missing?

Comment: `range()` doesn't include the end. Do `daterange_2 = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days + 1)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the ranges of both `daterange` and `daterange_2` to include all the necessary dates:

```
import datetime

# First date range is next week from monday to sunday:
next_week_day = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
monday = next_week_day - datetime.timedelta(days=next_week_day.weekday())
sunday = monday + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

daterange = [monday + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (sunday - monday).days + 1)]

# Second daterange can be anything:
start = datetime.date(2020, 8, 2)
end = datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)
daterange_2 = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days + 1)]

# then I create a list to add matching days to create the new range
date_list = []
for date in daterange:
    for date_2 in daterange_2:
        if date_2 == date:
            date_list.append(date)

# and retrieve first and last day in list
first_date = date_list[0]
second_date = date_list[-1]

print(first_date, second_date)
print(type(first_date), type(second_date))
```